# Localization for Android Library application

Tags: android, localization, android-library

I am developing the library application, which is reused in many android applications. Now, I need to add the localization capability to my android library application.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

In the above link, localization deals with the resources. If I am using the resources in the library project tends to have the same resources in the referenced android application also. Is there any other way to achieve the localization in android library project.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add localization into your library project like a Standart Android project:
values-en,values-ru,values-uk and etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I deal with the RTL languages in android application resources.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to provide alternative sources as mentioned in [Providing alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)
So say for string file you can provider string files for different languages and device will choose which file to use according to device configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html . In the link above 4.2 only RTL language have been supported. How can I specify the Arabic,Hebrew..etc languages folder in my android application.?